# passing name of dataframe into a loop in r

Tags: r, function, dataframe

Here is just small example of my problem:

```
myfun <- function (dataframe) {
namef <- paste (dataframe, ".raw", sep = "")
return(namef)
}
xy <- data.frame (A = 1:10, B = 11:20)

myfun(xy)
[1] "1:10.raw"  "11:20.raw"
```

What I want to return is name of file "xy.raw" in this case.

names(dataframe) will not work as it will give the names of data frame columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try :

```
paste(substitute(dataframe),".raw,sep="")
```